# Why can't I access a CSV file saved from Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, export-to-csv

I am writing a dataframe to csv, but I am unable to view or access the file from file explorer. Any suggestions on how to access the file directly from file explorer?

I am using pandas functions "to_csv" and "read_csv" in Jupyter Notebook. I am successful in writing and reading from the csv file, which indicates the command is working.[image]

However, the csv file is not present in File Explorer.

[image]

Comment: From where are you opening the jupyter notebook from?

Comment: Run `! dir` in a new cell to get the current directory... is it what you expect?

Comment: @ChrisA Yes, I can view the files using ! dir command. How would I open them directly? Any reason why I can't access them via file explorer?

Comment: Not sure, what about trying `! explorer .`

Comment: Sth I noticed is gastats.head() contains two columns date and WPIP and you save it as csv but when you read and list [1:3] 'date' shouldnt be seen.how come it is displayed

Comment: Ok got it...the index is there as well!

Comment: Yes, thanks for looking into this @RamShankerG